# multiple plots in same figure with one axis via python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, subplot

I'm trying to plot one diagram of both cyclical components(gdp and hoursworked) using HP-filters and matplotlib in python. Currently only getting one figure to plot and other figure is flatline(HoursWorked is flatlined) (Image below). Any pointers on how to improve code.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pandas_datareader import data
import datetime as dt

start, end = dt.datetime(1965, 1, 1), dt.datetime(2016,12, 31)

gdp = data.DataReader('GDPC1', 'fred', start, end)
HoursWorked = data.DataReader('PRSCQ', 'fred', start, end)

plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(gdp)

plt.title('RealGDP and Hours Worked')
cycle, trend = sm.tsa.filters.hpfilter(gdp, 1600)

plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(HoursWorked)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticklabels([])

plt.show()
```

[image]
[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4ME5.png)

Comment: `prscq` is not defined in this code snippet.

Comment: @Crispin typo, it's hours worked.

Comment: What does `HoursWorked` look like? It could be that your y axis has scaled in order to encompass all the data for `gdp` and therefore `HoursWorked` just looks like a flat line. You could try just plotting `HoursWorked` on its own to see?

Comment: @davidG attached an image for HoursWorked. That could very much be the reason. However I need them on one graph to view trend, is it possible to scale up to accommodate data points. Im fairly new to matplotlib and python as a whole

Comment: @pyt the answer below will do the trick

Answer (score 2):

I think you would want to use a twin axes. I.e. you want two axes which sit on top ofeach other and share the same x scale, but have a different y scale. This can be done with the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas_datareader.data 
import datetime as dt

start, end = dt.datetime(1965, 1, 1), dt.datetime(2016,12, 31)

gdp = pandas_datareader.data.DataReader('GDPC1', 'fred', start, end)
HoursWorked = pandas_datareader.data.DataReader('PRSCQ', 'fred', start, end)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax.plot(gdp, label="GDP")
ax2.plot(HoursWorked, color="C2", label="HoursWorked")

ax.set_title('RealGDP and Hours Worked')

ax.legend(loc=2)
ax2.legend(loc=4)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Any chance you also know how to have only one caption?